# Reset markers icon in google maps v3 Javascript

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am changing the icon for the current selected marker with something like this:

```
var icon_active = {
    url: '/2018/images/map/location.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 42)
};
markers[window.VARS.marker_currently_open].setIcon(icon_active);
```

The problem I'm having, is how to reset it back to what it was before? I've tried to find a list of the standard icons, ie:

[image]

Could anyone advise me on how to do this? What I was trying to find was a list of the different (default) icons that are available, and find the standard one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the default icon, call `marker.setIcon(null)`.

i.e.:

```
markers[window.VARS.marker_currently_open].setIcon(null);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gajkrpo4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  })
  markers.push(marker);
  window.VARS = {
    marker_currently_open: 0
  }
  var icon_active = {
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 42)
  };
  markers[window.VARS.marker_currently_open].setIcon(icon_active);
  setTimeout(function() {
    markers[window.VARS.marker_currently_open].setIcon(null);
  }, 5000);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```